# auto toggle between divs. settimeout not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have created a div with three slides that user can toggle between them
but the problem is i'm trying to make it as a auto slide but the settimeout it's not working.the toggle button works fine i can switch between slides without a problem.
here is the code

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  if (n > slide.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slide.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
      slide[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slide[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);
}
```

and the stylesheet :

```
html , body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box ;
  text-align: center ;
}
/* Top */
.top {
overflow: hidden;
}
/* Navbar */
.navbar {
  display: flex ;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  background: transparent ;   
  align-items: center ;
  justify-content: space-between ;
  z-index: 9999;
  position : absolute ;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none ;
  color : #fff ;
  font-size: 17px;
  flex-shrink: 1 ;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navbar a:nth-last-child(3) {
  margin-left: auto ;
}
/* slideshow */
.slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.slide {
  padding: 100px;
  color : #fff;
}
#slide1 {
  background: url(bm2.jpg) no-repeat center center ;
  background-size: cover ;
  height: 457px;
}
#slide2 {
  background: url(bm3.jpg) no-repeat center center ;
  background-size: cover ;
  height: 457px;
}
#slide3 {
  background: url(bm1.jpg) no-repeat center center ;
  background-size: cover ;
  height: 457px;
}
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.prev {
  left : 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
```

i'll be glad to know what's wrong with my code or what i'm doing wrong here

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR: Solution:** Anonymus functions!

Replace this line:

```
setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);
```

with these:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    plusSlides(1);
}, 2000);
```

---

**There are multiple problems here as I can tell:**

```
setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);
```

**1: You are trying to call the wrong function.**

I think it's better to call `plusSlides`.

```
setTimeout(plusSlides, 2000);
```

---

**2: You don't pass any arguments, but your functions require one.**

```
setTimeout(plusSlides(1), 2000);
```

---

**3: It will throw a callstack exception.**

When you call a function like this, setTimeout wants to call the return value of `plusSlides(1)` which is `undefined` in this case, but the bigger problem is, that it calls itself infinite amount of times without any delay. So it creates an infinite loop.

For example, if you have this code:

```
function add(a + b) {
    return a + b;
}
setTimeout(add(1 + 2), 1000);
```

JavaScript interprets it like this:

```
setTimeout(3, 1000);
```

So you need to pass an anonymus function or a function name.

Comment: thanks a lot Aron , i just stared to learn js and your answer help me a lot.
i wrote my code again from your JSfiddle that you created and it worked

Comment: @feriii I'm happy that I could help. :) (There is another problem with the recursive setTimeout version: Every time you click on a button, you initiate a new parallel recursion, so the slideshow is going crazy. That's why I changed it to setInterval.)

Comment: i noticed it , there was another problem too , when i wrote the script again it wasn't working till like 10 or 15 seconds , then i just added the script file link before the closing body tag.it was some onload problem i guess.tnx anyway

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call some function regularly every `n` seconds use function [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). Also you need to call `plusSlides()` and not `showSlides()` to update `slideIndex` value.

So remove `setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);` line from `showSlides` function and at the end of your code add this:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    plusSlides(1); 
}, 2000);
```

Comment: thanks a lot but when i add the setInterval to my code it's not working.then i added the code to PlusSlides() function but until i click on the prev/next button it wouldn't work.then it will just toggle between two slides

Comment: Can you please create fiddle with your code? It would be easier to help you.

Comment: You have to remove setTimeout(showSlides, 2000) from showSlides() but do not change plusSlides().